# Article pages: is there a way with a code to 'write' one or more fields inside the page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, publishing-page

The Article page has a lot of properties that might be useful to read on the main page and not as a 'property' of the page only. Is there a code to occasionally surface any value (contact, Modified, etc) on the page in a text box? something easy that you can put in a script editor just on the pages you need and with the column field you need from that very page. I do not want a code for the master page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId` you query field values of page item (article page) and once you get the value you can bind it to any control you want on the page.

```
Value of Title :<label id="lbltipAddedComment"></label> <br/> 
Value of OtherColumn : <label id="lbltipAddedComment1"></label> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',getPageProperties);
    var item = "";

    function getPageProperties()
    {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
        item = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId)
        context.load(item, "Title", "Test");
        context.executeQueryAsync(mySuccessFunction,myErrorFunction);
    }

    function mySuccessFunction()
    {
        var itemTitle = item.get_item("Title");
        var itemTest= item.get_item("Test");
document.getElementById('lbltipAddedComment').innerHTML = itemTitle ;
document.getElementById('lbltipAddedComment1').innerHTML = itemTest;
    }

    function myErrorFunction()
    {
        alert("F");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83274/discussion-on-answer-by-bhaskar-dhone-article-pages-is-there-a-way-with-a-code).